# SSL Certificate with wildcard in common name

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a host where there are multiple websites running :
webex1dev
webex2dev
webex3dev
webex4dev

ow we have to create a certificate for all these websites. Will the sites work on ssl if we request a new certificate with CN as webex*dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, this is allowed by [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) (and others) but is not well supported in practice.

For example, [openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/4293) does not support it at all and you are likely to run into issues with both clients and servers.

Instead, you should put the list of hosts in the Subject Alternative Name extension.

Comment: Thanks, if i put hosts in SAN... and new websites get set up on same host... we will have to regenerate the certificate with new SAN..

Comment: Yes, or use a server that can handle multiple certificates and can pick the correct one based on SNI.